# Why the Regular Expression didn't work well in Pywinauto

Tags: python, regex, google-chrome, pywinauto

```
from pywinauto import application

app=application.Application()
3. app.connect(title_re = "/Zero Hedge$/")
4. app.connect(title_re = "/| Zero Hedge/")
```

I want to get a window of Chrome like this: http://www.zerohedge.com/news/2016-02-18/markets-ignore-fundamentals-and-chase-headlines-because-they-are-dying

As you see when you visit the website, the website title contains "| Zero Hedge" in the last part of it or only "Zero Hedge" contained.

However, I still get a WindowNotFoundError raised in no matter line 3 or line 4. Why the Regular Expression didn't work?

Thank you for all your help!

Comment: Your first regex is probably not working because you are using "$" as the end of string anchor but you followed it with another character, "/". The second regex probably doesn't work because the "|" is an or operator within regular expressions so you need to escape it with "\".  See this for details: http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html

Comment: First, deeply thank you for your help! I learned regex in a Chinese website which said that if I want to detect certain string in the last, I should use "/str$/". So you mean I should remove the last "/". Like this: app.connect(title_re = "/Zero Hedge$") ? About the second regex, I add a "\" like this: app.connect(title_re = "/\| Zero Hedge/"). It still not works... However, really thank you for your help!

Comment: Try your regexes again without the leading and trailing "/" characters.

Comment: Oh my god, I use this: app.connect(title_re = "\| Zero Hedge"). Still not working... It always raises WindowNotFoundError.

Comment: Well... I use app.connect(title_re = "| Zero Hedge") and it works. But it found a lot of windows match it. I think I have to create a different topic to figure out what happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this to get a list of all of your windows/titles:

```
from pywinauto import findwindows

print findwindows.find_windows(title_re=".*")
```

That should get you a list of all windows and then build your regex based off the results.